# Polars subtract numpy 1xn array from n columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, python-polars

I am struggling with polars. I have a dataframe and an numpy array. I would like to subtract them.

```
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd

df = pl.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4), schema=['#', 'x', 'y', 'z'])

arr = np.array([-10, -20, -30])


df.select(
    pl.col(r'^[x|y|z]$')
).apply(
    lambda x: np.array(x) - arr
)

shape: (6, 3)
┌───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ column_0  ┆ column_1  ┆ column_2  │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 10.143819 ┆ 21.875335 ┆ 29.682364 │
│ null      ┆ null      ┆ null      │
│ null      ┆ null      ┆ null      │
│ null      ┆ null      ┆ null      │
│ null      ┆ null      ┆ null      │
│ null      ┆ null      ┆ null      │
└───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

So now the subtraction is only applied at the first row.

But if I try to calculate the norm for example, then it works for every row:

```
df.select(
    pl.col(r'^[x|y|z]$')
).apply(
    lambda x: np.sum((np.array(x) - arr)**2)**0.5
)
shape: (6, 1)
┌───────────┐
│ apply     │
│ ---       │
│ f64       │
╞═══════════╡
│ 38.242255 │
│ 37.239545 │
│ 38.07624  │
│ 36.688312 │
│ 38.419194 │
│ 36.262196 │
└───────────┘

# check if it is correct:
np.sum((df.to_pandas()[['x', 'y', 'z']].to_numpy() - arr)**2, axis=1) ** 0.5
>>> array([38.24225488, 37.23954478, 38.07623986, 36.68831161, 38.41919409,
       36.2621962 ])
```

In pandas one can do it like this:

```
df.to_pandas()[['x', 'y', 'z']] - arr

x   y   z
0   10.143819   21.875335   29.682364
1   10.360651   21.116404   28.871060
2   9.777666    20.846593   30.325185
3   9.394726    19.357053   29.716592
4   9.223525    21.618511   30.390805
5   9.751234    21.667080   27.393393
```

One way it will work is to do it for each column separately. But that means a lot of the same code, especially when the number of columns are increasing:

```
df.select(
    pl.col('x') - arr[0], pl.col('y') - arr[1], pl.col('z') - arr[2]
)
```

Comment: Change your lambda function to `lambda x: tuple(np.array(x) - arr)` and try again.

Comment: No that did not work, it subtracted arr[0] from all columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things going on in this question.

The first is that you really really [don't want to use `apply`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/custom_functions.html?highlight=apply#to-apply) unless you're doing something that is a custom python function

> the apply expression passes elements of the column to the python function.
> Note that you are now running python, this will be slow.

There's not really a polars way to do what you want.  When polars sees `pl.col(r'^[x|y|z]$').expr` it's going to identify each column that fits the regex and then there will be a thread doing the work of whatever the rest of the expression is.  The expression doesn't know where in the order it was.  It only knows what its data is and what it's supposed to do.  Therefore, there's nothing you can put in the `expr` for it to know which element in the array to access.

To get at what you want, you have to do something like @ignoring_gravity had but you can use the `re` module.

```
import re
df.select(pl.col(col)-arr[i] 
          for i, col in enumerate(filter(re.compile(r'^[x|y|z]$').match, df.columns)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option that avoids the `re` import would be:

```py
res = df.select(
    pl.col(col) - c
    for col, c in zip(df.select(pl.col(r'^[x|y|z]$')).columns, arr)
)
```

This is slightly slower for very small dataframes (I guess because it is then dominated by the regex speed) but equally fast for larger ones.

Comment: In your zip, I wonder if doing `df.filter(False).select(pl.col(r'^[x|y|z]$')).columns` would be a performance improvement since it'll prevent it from returning rows internally (maybe it does that anyway, I'm not sure). Either way I like this trick.  You could also do `pl.DataFrame([x-y for x,y in zip(df.select(pl.col(r'^[x|y|z]$')), arr)])`

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Interesting suggestions! I've just run a `timeit` for a dataframe with 25 million rows and about 30 columns and found that your first suggestion is on par with the other two. The direct column-`zip` though was significantly slower, which I didn't suspect at first.

Answer (score 1):

You can match the pandas output

```py
In [15]: df.to_pandas()[['x', 'y', 'z']] - arr
Out[15]:
           x          y          z
0  10.342991  21.258934  29.083287
1  10.136803  21.543558  28.168207
2  11.900141  19.557348  29.490541
3   9.192346  19.498689  28.195094
4   9.219745  20.330358  29.005278
5  11.853378  19.458095  30.357041
```

with

```py
In [17]: df.select([pl.col(col)-arr[i] for i, col in enumerate(['x', 'y', 'z'])])
Out[17]:
shape: (6, 3)
┌───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ x         ┆ y         ┆ z         │
│ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 10.342991 ┆ 21.258934 ┆ 29.083287 │
│ 10.136803 ┆ 21.543558 ┆ 28.168207 │
│ 11.900141 ┆ 19.557348 ┆ 29.490541 │
│ 9.192346  ┆ 19.498689 ┆ 28.195094 │
│ 9.219745  ┆ 20.330358 ┆ 29.005278 │
│ 11.853378 ┆ 19.458095 ┆ 30.357041 │
└───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your input. Your first solution `df.select([pl.col('x')+10, pl.col('y')+20, pl.col('z')+30])` was already posted in my question. That does not satisfy me with the "easy" use of polars, especially when the arrays are getting larger. The second solution is something workable, but in my opinion it does not make use of the easy regex selection of polars. But thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I do not think it really solves the python-polars problem but it is a nice workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I saw for a short time the answer I was looking for, but the comment is removed.

The solution was to return a tuple:

```
df.select(
    pl.col(r'^[x|y|z]$')
).apply(
    # lambda x: np.array(x) - arr  # old code
    lambda x: tuple(np.array(x) - arr)  # new code
)
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I got confused and rechecked the result :(

Comment: well it works for the `select` option. It does not with `with_columns` for example: `df.with_columns(
    pl.col('^[x|y|z]$').apply(lambda x: tuple(np.array(x) - arr))
)` did not work...

Comment: Yes. And I don't like the solution (that's why I only added a comment).

Comment: `apply` will be slower, you probably want to avoid this solution if you can

Comment: @ignoring_gravity slower than what? slower than select and subtract it per column like you showed in your answer? I am using that method at the moment to get things done.

Comment: yes, that's right - Dean MacGregor explains very well why you probably want to avoid `apply` if you can

Comment: If you're calling numpy methods - perhaps it's simpler to just `df.select(r"^[xyz]$").to_numpy() - arr` - Also, your regex matches columns named `|` e.g. `pl.DataFrame({"a": ["one"], "|": ["two"]}).select(pl.col(r"^[x|y|z]$"))` it should just be `[xyz]`